# Robot Framework - pybot command output

Tags: python, batch-file, jenkins, robotframework

I have a Jenkins job that's trigger Robot Framework test suites. I configure this job with "Execute Windows Batch Command" in build step. There is a pybot command in this batch command line. But I need a return code to use execute another script or finish the execution.
So, how can I get a return code or output statement from **pybot command** to realize execution's success/failed status?

**UPDATE**
I added an if block. When suite is success, it seems work fine. But when suite failed, it couldn't go into else block. Did i miss something?

```
pybot --suite login --argumentfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\live_smoke_CicekSepeti\workspace\Execution\server\settings\ciceksepeti_argumenfile_LIVE_chrome.txt" --variablefile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\live_smoke_CicekSepeti\workspace\Execution\server\settings\ciceksepeti_variable_LIVE_chrome.py" --loglevel INFO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\live_smoke_CicekSepeti\workspace"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0
 (exit)
else (pybot --rerunfailed "output.xml" --output "rerun.xml" --loglevel INFO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\live_smoke_CicekSepeti\workspace"&rebot --merge "output.xml" "rerun.xml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following variable contains the return code:

```
%ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: I added your response as an another build step but it gives me output as "'0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." even tests failed or successed.

Comment: You have to use it in the same build step (to catch the relevant return code). In a new build step, it's normal that the value is 0 (because no batch/process has been launched). After your pybot call, you just have to add a dos/batch code block to have a look to the %ERRORLEVEL% variable.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @Bruno. I did it as you mentioned with an if block and updated question. Could you check? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to use NEQ instead of EQU? (and replace the exit with the other Pybot command)

Comment: I did it but got the same result.

Comment: If you replace your Pybot command with echo "your message", do you see the echo output in the Jenkins log?

Comment: Do you mean like "echo endofpybotcommand if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 echo ifblock else echo ifelseblock"?

Comment: if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 echo "This is a test". Just to check if the if statement is working.

Comment: So you have a problem with your Pybot command :) If my first answer help, please vote for it.

Comment: Actually it's even work fine but I guess there is something about implementation with batch command. Thanks @Bruno.